# MySQL INNER JOIN, get the last entries, not the first

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb, sql-order-by

I am having an issue with my multi join SQL statement, where I need to get the last entries of the table and not the first. I have 3 tables that I try to query based on this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id,i.hz,i.v,i.t,i.u,i.temp, i.c1, s.server, s.hostname, h.codes,s.cpus FROM `dc_servers` AS s INNER JOIN `dc_hardware` AS h ON  s.server = h.server INNER JOIN `dc_systemusage` AS i ON s.server = i.server GROUP BY i.server
```

The tables `dc_servers` & `dc_hardware` only has 1 row per server, however the table `dc_systemusage` has many rows with the same server, as new info is being added.

When I run the query, I get the first entries from the `dc_systemusage`, but I need to get the latest entries from that table, for me it sounds like I need an `ORDER BY`, however if I add that to the end of the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id,i.hz,i.v,i.t,i.u,i.temp, i.c1, s.server, s.hostname, h.codes,s.cpus FROM `dc_servers` AS s INNER JOIN `dc_hardware` AS h ON  s.server = h.server INNER JOIN `dc_systemusage` AS i ON s.server = i.server GROUP BY i.server ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

then I am just ordering the result, which is not what I am looking for.

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction as for how I can get the latest rows and not the first from the table `dc_systemusage`

I hope I have provided the needed information to guide me, else please do let me know and I will add whatever is neeeded.

Thank you all.

Comment: What is there in your `dc_systemusage` table that identifies the latest entry?  A timestamp?   You will need to build a query to get its max value by  server.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer - There is the ID as AUTO_INCREMENT, the `i.id`, there is also a timestamp, but figured it would be easier to use the id field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find dc_systemusage lastest ids in subquery and use with WHERE ... IN

```
SELECT i.id,i.hz,i.v,i.t,i.u,i.temp, i.c1, s.server, s.hostname, h.codes,s.cpus
FROM `dc_servers` AS s
INNER JOIN `dc_hardware` AS h ON  s.server = h.server
INNER JOIN `dc_systemusage` AS i ON s.server = i.server
WHERE i.id IN (SELECT max(dc_systemusage.id) FROM dc_systemusage GROUP BY dc_systemusage.server)
```

and check a great answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800572/7174186

Comment: Thank you so much, was what I was looking for! I did search and query other questions to see if there was what I was looking for, but I guess I used wrong search terms to get the right answer. But thank you very much. And as a bonus, the query is also much faster than what it was before which is a huge bonus.